# mongoose -schema option updated at for specific field

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

```
const schemaOptions = {
  versionKey: false,
  timestamps: { createdAt: 'created_at', updatedAt: 'updated_at' },
};
```

i used the following in my code.

it updated the `updatedAt` field if any of the field gets updated in the schema

is there an option to specify to update the `updatedAt` on only update of some specific fields in schema

Comment: you need to add custom logic for that

Comment: is there a way to create custom logic and override the existing one